# Cannot ssh into Windows 10 native SSH server?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, putty, sshd

Hi have enabled `sshd` server in my Windows 10 Home edition and I can `ssh` into this PC from local `Putty` client using Windows 10's local IP Address(IP from home router), however, I cannot `ssh` into this PC from another computer, Centos7, it times out. Can anyone help in that regard? I have searched online but all I can find is `how to enable SSH in Windows 10` etc..

Thanks

Comment: If you can ssh into it locally but not from another machine, that most likely means you have not opened port 22 in the Windows firewall.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have added Firewall rule for opening port 22 ad it worked.